# Étale morphism over unirational/uniruled variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers, kodaira-dimension

Suppose we have an étale morphism between smooth quasi-projective (complex) varieties $X \rightarrow Y$ and assume that $Y$ is unirational. I am wondering whether we can somehow deduce that $X$ is unirational, or rationally connected, or uniruled, or has negative Kodaira dimension.
And what if $Y$ is just uniruled but non-necessarily unirational?

Comment: An étale cover of a rational curve is a disjoint union of rational curves...

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi  What you write is correct for an etale morphism that is also *finite*, e.g., proper.  However, the OP only indicates that the morphism is etale, not etale and finite.

Comment: @JasonStarr: I guessed that finite was implict, but of course you are right...

Comment: Anyway, over $\mathbb{C}$ and in the projective and uniruled case I think that there is no non-trivial cover, due to a result of Serre saying that every smooth, unirational variety is simply connected, right?

Comment: Without properness assumptions you cannot deduce anything. For instance take *any* projective variety $X$ of dimension $n$; a general projection to $Y=\mathbb{P^n}$ is finite. Just take out of $X$ the ramification locus, you get an étale map to $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Yes, finite was implicit in my mind, sorry for not having pointed it out.  

@abx: well, you're right. But I don't get where the properness assumption should intervene. If you take out of $X$ the ramification locus of the projection and consider its image in $\mathbb{P}^n$, you have an étale finite morphism of quasi-projective variety, isn't it?  
I wonder what might happen if I consider a more precise situation, such as for instance the case where $Y$ is the quotient of $X$ by a finite group (always assuming all the other hypotheses).

Comment: "assuming all the other hypotheses": I am lost with which hypotheses you want to make. Anyway there is no reasonable statement of the type you ask for.

Comment: Well, I meant a quotient of $X$ by a finite group which gives a $Y$ such that the quotient map is finite étale, and both are smooth quasi-projective varieties. But I am afraid you are right, it's not reasonable to expect any statement of the kind I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the case where $Y$ is unirational and projective, there exists no non-trivial étale cover of $Y$. In fact, the fundamental group of a complex, projective, smooth unirational variety is trivial, see

J. P. Serre: [*On the fundamental group of a unirational variety*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-34.4.481), J. Lond. Math. Soc. **34**, 481-484 (1959). [ZBL0097.36301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0097.36301).